# Playframework 2.5 : FileNotFoundException when trying to open file in root folder

Tags: java, playframework, java-io, fileinputstream, playframework-2.5

I'm using a proprietary API which creates a temporary file in the root directory of my application. In development mode, I have no problem with it, but after having packaged the application and launching it, a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown. The stack trace shows that the open method of FileInputStream fails (it's called by the proprietary API, I can't use getResourceAsStream method).

In all cases I can see the file created in `target/universal/stage/`, but the application, packaged in the JAR can't open it.

What is this issue ? How do I solve this ?

Comment: When running your programs through jar file in dist folder, it requires files to be in the same directory. Try to move your temporary file to dist folder, or jar file to directory where your file appears. But i'm not sure :)

Comment: Pierre, can you give a more concrete example? Where the file is created? How do you try to load that file?

Comment: In this proprietary API is there a way to change the path of this temporary file. There is a [place for temporary files in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: I think the example wouldn't help. The proprietary API hides everything. I'm not sure there is a way to change the path of the temporary file, the documentation is... short... Changing java.io.tmpdir does nothing.
The file is created in the root folder of the application (target/universal/stage).

Comment: So the file is created in target/universal/stage. What tries to read it after and fails? Something in that api or your application? and what path it tries to load?